# how to synchronize phpmyadmin database

Tags: git, symfony, github

i'm new in using git and git-hub for versionning my project and i need your help guys concerning this issue 
so, i'm working with a friend on a project in symfony2 ,my database is stored in phpmyadmin
and i wanted to use git and git-hub so that both of us can conserve the changes he makes in the code source but the problem is that i don't know if it's the same with the database
i need a way to conserve and synchronize the changes we both make in the database and the code source as well 
any suggestions ?
and thanks :)
to be more specific i want to find a way so that the objects i add to the data base in local ,can also be added to my friends database 
for example i have an entity "Questions" after adding the questions i need 
my friend should also find those questions i added in his database

Answer (score 0):

If you use Doctrine ORM in that Symfony project and the schema was either created by Doctrine or is (more or less) equivalent to the schema Doctrine would create, you can use the `doctrine:schema:update` command which is included in Doctrine and hence Symfony.

That means: update your code (e.g.: add a new entity property with an `@ORM\Column(...)` annotation), then run `./app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` on a dev system or rather `./app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` on a production system to update the schema or (in the latter case) review the changes which would be made. (`app/console` would be for Symfony2, whereas with a new Symfony3 project, it would have to be `bin/console`.)

Apart from that, there is also a separate project called [Doctrine Migrations](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations) for which a Symfony bundle is available.

Comment: so you mean if my friend pull the project  use git and then run ./app/console doctrine:schema:update --force or 
./app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
he will get in his database the data i have added ?

Comment: The Doctrine commands I mentioned operate on the database schema – *not* on the data (i.e.: after running the commands, the table definitions will be up to date, but not contain other data than before). If you want to make sure that every developer working on the project has some defined data, this is a different issue. The term to look out for is “fixtures”, e.g. see http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html

Answer (score 0):

read the symphony documentation, you need read about Doctrine and Database.
I hope this link will help you: https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html